# Reducing hardware-reserved memory

Tags: memory, bios

First, I'd like to tell you the components inside my computer, so there will be no confusion later on:

•Motherboard: MSI 970A-G46 (AMD) with click-BIOS II

•Memory: Crucial Ballistix Sport 8 GB (4x2GB) DDR3, 1600 Mhz

•OS: Windows 8 64-bit

•CPU: AMD FX-6300 hexa-core, OC'd to 4.2 GHz

•Video card: Sapphire Radeon HD 7850, 1 GB RAM

When I constructed my computer, I put 8 GB of RAM inside. For the first 3 weeks, everything functioned normally, and Windows was able to recognize & use all of the 8 GB. 
But after that, the available RAM (as in Task Manager) dropped to 4 GB. Task manager said that the other 4 GB is hardware-reserved.
I find it ridiculous that the hardware should need 4 GB of memory to operate. It should be less than 32 MB. 
So I tried to go into MS config, and uncheck the "Maximum memory" option under the 'Boot' tab. It was already unchecked. 
I also tried adjusting it to 8 GB, but that also did nothing.

So is there any way I can manually lower the hardware-reserved RAM on my system, either from Windows or the BIOS? I don't see any setting in click BIOS II which does that.
I never, ever updated the BIOS or flashed it, or anything like that.

Comment: Can you post an image of Task Manager? It isn't unusual for newer versions of Windows to occupy as much RAM as possible.

Comment: I second Doktoro's comment.  Even better would be use post the results of Sysinternal's Rammap.

Comment: I would prefer to see the windows resource monitors cute graphical display of physical memory in the memory tab. My system has about 64MB hardware reserved show there.  In your motherboard bios is the memory set to "extended memory"?  It can be called diffferent things, but it is the switch for being 64bit or not in the bios itself.